# how to parse nested inputStream to JSON in java?

Tags: java, json

I have an object that content inputStream object and list of that objects, I'm trying to parse it to client through JSON but I couldn't figure out how

the object:

```
public product(int id, int type, float price, float length, String color, InputStream img){
               this.id = id; this.price = price; ...}
```

what I'm trying to do:

```
 List<Product> list = db.getProducts();
 String json = "";
 if( list.size() > 0)
 {
     json = new Gson().toJson(list);
     System.out.println("product servlet >> " + list);
 } 

 response.getWriter().write(json);
 break;
```

The problem is in the line json = new Gson.toJson(list), it can't get the InputStream object

Comment: Why is `img` an `InputStream` and not a `byte[]`? You're obviously not concerned that the image can be too large for your available memory, so stick with that and just use `byte[]`. You will of course need to use an adapter to serialize that as e.g. Base-64, but that's easy enough with lots of examples on the web.

Comment: because I thought that when you read blob from the db u need to use InputStream, am I wrong?

Comment: ok, I will try to use byte[]

Comment: You can use `InputStream` or `byte[]` when reading a blob. Which you choose mostly depends on the size, e.g. a 10 GB 4K Movie is probably not going to fit in memory, but a 4 MB JPEG image will fit just fine.